# Why is $x \wedge x=0$, exterior algebra

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-algebra

My question is about the basics of the exterior algebra. Why is $x\wedge x=0$?
I still struggle with the definitions so i can't see why this is trivial.

I'm reffering to
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExteriorAlgebra.html
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WedgeProduct.html

I am thankful for any help!

Comment: The cited definition is wrong in char. 2. Use Wikipedia. Actually, $x \wedge x = 0$ is part of the correct definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because one of the defining features of exterior algebras is that they anticommute. Specifically, we have for any $x, y$ that
$$
x \wedge y = -y \wedge x
$$
If we happen to have $y = x$, then we get
$$
x \wedge x = -x\wedge x
$$
which means that $x \wedge x$ is its own negative, and therefore, unless you are working in characteristic $2$, must be $0$.

To circumvent the "unless you're working in char $2$", the property $x \wedge x = 0$ is really part of the definition of the wedge product.

Comment: $x\wedge y=-y\wedge x$ is true if $x$ and $y$ have odd degrees. (I'm not sure whether OP only wants the justification for $x\in\Lambda^1V=V$).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf $x, y \in V$ was what I was thinking about. But yes, you're right.